# Image resizing not working with png images

Tags: php, gd

it not work with png 
created a thumb png but haven't data , like null data :D
with jpg , jpeg still working without error 
why ?

```
function thumbnail($pathtoFile,$thumWidth,$pathtoThumb) {

    //infor of image
    $infor = pathinfo($pathtoFile);

    // Setting the resize parameters 
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($pathtoFile); 

    $modwidth = $thumWidth; 
    $modheight = floor( $height * ( $modwidth / $width )); 


    // Resizing the Image 
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight);

    switch(strtolower($infor['extension'])) {
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($pathtoFile); 
            break;

        case 'gif':
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($pathtoFile); 
            break;

        case 'png':
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($pathtoFile); 
            break;
    }

    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth,
            $modheight, $width, $height);

    switch(strtolower($infor['extension'])) {
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
            imagejpeg($thumb,$pathtoThumb, 70); 
            break;
        case 'gif':
            imagegif($thumb,$pathtoThumb, 70); 
            break;
        case 'png':

            imagepng($thumb,$pathtoThumb, 70); 
            break;
    }

    //destroy tmp
    imagedestroy($thumb);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working because [`imagepng()`](http://php.net/imagepng) third argument must be between 0 and 9. It indicates the compression level of the png image (0 being no compression). 70 is not a valid value.

```
imagepng($thumb, $pathtoThumb, 9);
```

Also, [`imagegif()`](http://php.net/imagegif) only accepts two arguments. Technically, your call should be:

```
imagegif($thumb, $pathtoThumb);
```